# MongoClient not working when properties read from config file

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have an issue while connecting to mongoDb from python3.
I have a configuration file where the host,username and password is provided and the data needs to be read from a configuration file. I am reading the configuration using ConfigObj. The problem is the following.
If I create the MongoClient using a static string then the client is working fine when I am calling `cursor.next()` but when the MongoClient is being created from the config file then I am getting the following error.
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.

Working Code.

```
client=MongoClient("mongodb://dummyuser:password@1.1.1.1:27071/default_db?authSource=auth_database",
maxPoolSize=10))
```

If I create a client in this format and later on from a function call global client and extact the documents using `cursor.next()` then it works fine. However if we use the following code.

```
client = MongoClient(host=configuration['host'],
                   port=27071,
                   username=configuration['user'],
                   password=configuration['password'],
                   authSource=configuration['auth_database']))
```

After creating a client like this if we are calling `cursor.next()` then I am getting the following error.

```
  File "basepath/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 159, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

I am not able to understand what is changing. Please help me.

The config file is of the format.

```
[mongodb]

 [[connection]]
  host = 1.1.1.1
  port = 27071
  user = dummy_user
  password = password
  authentication_database = auth_data
```

and the dict read is ,

```
{'host': '1.1.1.1', 'user': 'dummy_user', 'password': 'password',  'authentication_database': 'auth_data', 'port': 27071}
```

Comment: Post the configuration ```dict```, and/or the configuration file you use to create the ```dict``` so we can help. Or maybe you don't have one?

Comment: Added the config file to the main post.

Comment: ```authentication_database = auth_data``` typo? Should it be ```authentication_database = auth_database``` to match the command line version?

Comment: sorry it is a typo. it is auth_database. I am giving the database name only.